# TS: Assert non null property of object

Tags: typescript

I want to tell TypeScript that I know for a fact that a property of my object is not null, but I don't want to assert the whole object as a type, because then I will loose some TS protection.

Let's consider this simplification of my code:

```js
// User type from DB
interface User {
  email: string | null
}

// Expected return type of getUsers()
interface Response {
  users: {
    email: string
  }[]
}

function getUsers(): Response {
  // Users are coming from Prisma ORM: **I don't control the User[] type which is being returned**
  const users: User[] = [{ email: 'hello@email.com' }, { email: 'hi@email.com' }]

  return { users } // Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
}
```

In this case, I know for a fact that none of the emails are null (in real life I applied a filter in my DB query to filter null email out), so I want that fact to be represented in my types.

**I tried:**

I know I can cast the whole response like so:

```js
return { users } as Response
```

But I don't like it, because I will have no TS error if I change my Response type:

```js
// No TS error if I change the Response type, but the code is obviously wrong: BAD
interface Response {
  users: {
    email: string
    name: string
  }[]
}
```

**I also tried:**

```js
// Does work, but that's a useless .map() just to make TS happy...
return {
  users: users.map(user => ({ ...user, email: user.email as string }))
}
```

Do you know another solution which I would have missed? Thank you!

Comment: If you're using prisma you can set the type to be required in the schema.prisma file with `email String` rather than `email String?` it depends on your DB setup though. If you can't or don't want to use this approach I would suggest a typeguard.

Comment: @spirift The email is nullable on the database... I used a filter in the query to make sure the result all have email as strings. Maybe it is an issue that needs to be fixed within Prisma rather than anything else...

Comment: I agree, I had thought that Prisma dynamically updated the return Type based on the filter you provide but sadly I was wrong

Comment: I've opened a feature request for this. Maybe it's something they can add https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/9508 There is a workaround there too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Required utility type.

Note I changed Response to XResponse because the playground thinks the Response interface is extending the Fetch API's Response interface

```js
// User type from DB
interface User {
  email: string | null
}

// Expected return type of getUsers()
interface XResponse {
  users: Required<User>[]
}

function getUsers(): XResponse {
  // Users are coming from Prisma ORM: **I don't control the User[] type which is being returned**
  const users: User[] = [{ email: 'hello@email.com' }, { email: 'hi@email.com' }]

  return { users } // Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFUGcFMCdQC4E8AO1QDNYHsC2oARAIQCgBLAOwTgwEMBjdKOUAbxNFGl1rIBsAXKEgJYlAOagAPqAoBXPnxIBfEiRCgAogA809agBNQsaAjmwKiVOmwZQ4081iQAFAEpyVGg3QANAErQkCjYFDBsHKByMM5CgQCOcmQmBgA8TgB8ANoAuipqGHIU%20mSh9o4xrm5CAUEhYejsnBpOkKC0JqD0eBKYOPgACmKQPKAA8v4AskIAVDMAkqAGoQDkCF2hoth8iAAWTDG5VmigAO67ZPS7oGRtAEbQvSZmFtAGc5HdYevRcJBCTiOAF5QFlWFwePwhCt9opsAABbi8PgAOm6uBWoGUABo2BDkdCLojIaj0ZjlHlIs9zJZwb9nFjQBoACrWUArERiCiSGTyRSY26ybDrWiQSBkcQUWh3PjoBDYY7oDmiCQrFEqIA)

Edit:
If you want to express that a property is potentially undefined you should use ?.

```js
// User type from DB
interface User {
  email?: string
}

// Expected return type of getUsers()
interface XResponse {
  users: Required<User>[]
}

function getUsers(): XResponse {
  // Users are coming from Prisma ORM: **I don't control the User[] type which is being returned**
  const users: Required<User>[] = [{ email: 'hello@email.com' }, { email: 'hi@email.com' }]

  return { users } // Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
}

const email = getUsers().users[0].email;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFUGcFMCdQC4E8AO1QDNYHsC2oARAIQCgBLAOwTgwEMBjdKOUAbxNFGl1rIBsA-AC5QkBLEoBzEgF8SJEKACiADzT1qAE1CxoCAK6wKiVOmwZQkvc1iQAFAEpyVGg3QANAErRIKbBRg2DlB9GFsRbwBHfTJdTQAeGwA%20AG0AXVl5DH0KDTJ-S2sw%20wcRLx8-APR2TkUbSFBaXVB6PClMHHwABQlIHlAAeU8AWREAKjGASVBNfwByBBb-cWw%20RAALJjD0kzRQAHd1snp10DIGgCNodt0DI2hNCeDWgMXQuEgI6GjYh8Sw1JpUAAXlAKVYXB4-BEc02fD42AAAtxeHwAHStXBzUAyAA0bEhqJhR2RUPRmOxMgywVuhmMEPethxoEUABVTKA5mIJBRJKAAD6gCj6eHY85C7CLWiQSBkSQUWgXPjoBDYXboLniKRzNGZEgvMSE-ggwoIeqONGMyApAAMaTRKP4AG4gA)

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I am looking for: if I do `const email = getUsers().users[0].email`, email will be of type `string | null` and not `string`

Comment: @PaulinTrognon That is because of the way you defined your interface. I will edit the answer to include what you want

Comment: The thing is, the interface is generated via Prisma ORM, so I can't control it. In the database, the email is either a string or null.